# How do I do namaz if I am a student?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, muslim-practices

How I do salat/namaz being a student? My school time begins at 9am and ends at 3:30pm, hence is it obligatory for me to do namaz? I am 17 yrs old and in 10th class. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Salah/Namaz is obligatory in any situation.

We all have been gone through from this situation, every school have lunch hour, if you want you can pray in your school anywhere, just bring a small cloth.

By doing so you will get a respect even from other religion people.